# Searching through a list of lists?

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I'm a bit new to python and I have a question. I have a bunch of words stored in a list of lists like the following:

```
[["Hello", "my", "name", "is", "world"], ["Hello", "World!"]]
```

And I have another list that has a list of words like so:

```
["Hello", "name"]
```

I would like to compare whether or not the 2nd list has any words in the list of lists, and if so, replace those in the list of lists with another word. In our example, `Hello` and `name` would be replaced like so:

```
[["replaced", "my", "replaced", "is", "world], ["replaced", "World!"]]
```

If anyone could help me that would be great! Thanks! I'm just not sure on how to access the list of lists' elements.

Answer (score 5):

Use a list comprehension and set:

```
>>> lis = [["Hello", "my", "name", "is", "world"], ["Hello", "World!"]]
>>> lis2 = ["Hello", "name"]
>>> s = set(lis2)           #if lis2 is huge
>>> [[x if x not in s else 'replaced' for x in item] for item in lis]
[['replaced', 'my', 'replaced', 'is', 'world'], ['replaced', 'World!']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The list comprehension approach is perhaps the most Pythonic/elegant way of doing the task. However, if you prefer an in-place replacement approach (instead of generating a new list) you could do it as follows:

Data definition:

```
data = [["Hello", "my", "name", "is", "world"], ["Hello", "World!"]]
check = ["Hello", "name"]
```

Alternative 1:

```
for i, lst in enumerate(data):
    for j, word in enumerate(lst):
        if word in check: data[i][j] = 'replaced'
```

Alternative 2:

```
for i in xrange(len(data)):
    for j in xrange(len(data[i])):
      if data[i][j] in check: data[i][j] = 'replaced'
```

In case of huge lists and few replacements, I guess this kind of approach is more resource efficient as making in-place substitutions takes less time and uses less memory than generating a new list from scratch (while doing the same number of iterations/comparisons/lookups).